# Subscribe to Prism EventAggregator events with Reflection

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, prism, eventaggregator

I want to subscribe to an EventAggregator event using Reflection, because I am trying to dynamically wire up event subscriptions between Prism modules at runtime. (I'm using Silverlight 5, Prism and MEF).

What I want to achieve is calling `_eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyType>().Subscribe(MyAction)` in one of my modules, but I am stuck at calling `_eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyType>()`. How can I proceed from there to call `Subscribe(MyAction)`?

Say my Event class is `public class TestEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<string> { }`. I don't know this at compile time, but I know the Type at runtime.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
 Type myType = assembly.GetType(typeName); //get the type from string

 MethodInfo method = typeof(IEventAggregator).GetMethod("GetEvent");
 MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);//get the EventAggregator.GetEvent<myType>() method

 generic.Invoke(_eventAggregator, null);//invoke _eventAggregator.GetEvent<myType>();
```

I would really appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without having to worry about the "type" of event you are invoking by using dynamics.

```
Type eventType = assembly.GetType(typeName);
MethodInfo method = typeof(IEventAggregator).GetMethod("GetEvent");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(eventType);
dynamic subscribeEvent = generic.Invoke(this.eventAggregator, null);

if(subscribeEvent != null)
{
    subscribeEvent.Subscribe(new Action<object>(GenericEventHandler));
}

//.... Somewhere else in the class

private void GenericEventHandler(object t)
{
}
```

Now you really never need to know what the "event type" is.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as:

```
var myEvent = generic.Invoke(eventAggregator, null) as CompositePresentationEvent<string>;
if (myEvent != null) 
    myEvent.Subscribe(MyAction);
```

Assuming you know the payload type.

Personally, I see the aggregated events that are consumed outside of a module as this module's API and I try to place them in some sort of a shared assembly that other modules can compile against.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I missed the `as CompositePresentationEvent<string>` part.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the case that the payload type is unknown here:

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/6244

> 1. Add EventAggregator.GetEvent(Type eventType) to get the event without generic parameters
> 2. Build an expression of type Action using reflection
> 3. Subscribe to event using reflection (i.e. calling Subscribe method) and passing Expression.Compile as the parameter.
>
> This works if KeepAlive is true.